# Taking too much time to boot the system..?

Tags: boot

I'm new to Linux platform , I needed a clean light weight Linux distro that's what I come up with elementary os . Also it looks really cool . But , the problem is its taking too much time to boot up , previously i had centos in my same vaio laptop , it boot up much faster than elementary os. It took more than half an hour to boot up and shows some failed error message line like ' failed to start show playmouth boot screen' and so many .. I would like to learn and continue to use Linux but it's really annoys.. 
My system is up to date , once got the login screen every things are fine , run smooth and fast ..

Here is the boot analyzed report ..

```
  20.063s systemd-rfkill.service
      8.956s mysql.service
      7.230s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      6.631s dev-sda6.device
      4.428s ModemManager.service
      4.008s apache2.service
      3.641s accounts-daemon.service
      2.999s grub-common.service
      2.862s apport.service
      2.538s irqbalance.service
      2.418s speech-dispatcher.service
      2.363s networking.service
      2.281s lightdm.service
      2.221s NetworkManager.service
      1.919s iio-sensor-proxy.service
      1.898s rsyslog.service
      1.897s pppd-dns.service
      1.897s alsa-restore.service
      1.891s gpu-manager.service
      1.670s avahi-daemon.service
      1.491s thermald.service
      1.285s polkitd.service
      1.262s systemd-udevd.service
      1.212s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-de73b405\x2dfa90\x2d4959\x2d8046\x2d984a86af0486.service
      1.189s keyboard-setup.service
      1.060s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
       885ms apparmor.service
       853ms systemd-modules-load.service
       686ms packagekit.service
       662ms systemd-logind.service
       657ms systemd-journald.service
       636ms ondemand.service
       556ms resolvconf.service
       440ms dev-mqueue.mount
       419ms dev-hugepages.mount
       417ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
       362ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
       319ms kmod-static-nodes.service
       292ms wpa_supplicant.service
       291ms console-setup.service
       288ms pantheon-parental-controls.service
       206ms systemd-user-sessions.service
       197ms systemd-update-utmp.service
       192ms colord.service
       191ms ufw.service
       180ms bluetooth.service
       175ms upower.service
       166ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       148ms systemd-journal-flush.service
       141ms systemd-sysctl.service
       138ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-32add840\x2d536f\x2d4dac\x2d84ab\x2d047b6c7c9525.swap
       134ms setvtrgb.service
       128ms systemd-remount-fs.service
       109ms openvpn.service
       104ms plymouth-read-write.service
        94ms udisks2.service
        75ms user@1000.service
        71ms rc-local.service
        62ms home.mount
        57ms systemd-random-seed.service
        49ms rtkit-daemon.service
        49ms systemd-timesyncd.service
        31ms snapd.socket
        19ms snapd.autoimport.service
        17ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
        15ms plymouth-start.service
         5ms ureadahead-stop.service
         4ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         4ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
         2ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

You can disable any service by runinng the command :

`sudo systemctl disable Service_name`

With this command the service will be disabled at boot. Try disabling the top two services and install a program called *preload* ( It cuts off boot-up time ) .

For installing it run :

`sudo apt-get install preload`

To hide the boot messages ( that long list ) : Press ESC or Num 0 when they show up.

Answer (score 0):

Ok..You can get your boot time by writing this command into the terminal :
`systemd-analyze`

To check how much time services are using :
`systemd-analyze blame | less`

To print the output to a file type :
`systemd-analyze blame > Boot.txt`

A *Boot.txt* file will be created in your home directory. You can then upload your file here so we can go through it and suggest you an optimal solution.

Meanwhile try to update your OS by :
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: My system is upto date already .. I did all the necessary steps just after installation ... Let me do the step you were suggested..

Comment: Im getting flickering screen with elementary os logo or some time loading tons of line on the screen continuously with some failed error message in between ...

Comment: you can see the video about the flickering screen ..https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8gYexQQfvxdN0NCM1hxQlM4bEN2ZDBVQTJMQXB6MFBpbHQw

Comment: What are the specs of your PC ?

Comment: 4gb ram ddr3 , 500gb hdd , intel HD graphics and cpu 2.2 ghz i3.. But I have win 7 installed already .. I'm trying to dual boot..

Comment: For elementary os I given 35 gb for root , 45 gb for home and 5 gb for swap volume..

Comment: Is your swap on ? I get slow boot ups when my swap is turned off.

Comment: Thanks for your help . But didn't worked well , I replaced elementary os with lxle Linux .. It's less resource hungry and booting fast .. Once again thanks..